# Catching a bash command error in a variable

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, postgresql

I'm using `psql`(PostgreSQL) command in a bash script:

```
function create_database () {
       sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE $1 WITH OWNER $2;" 2>ERROR
        if [[ $? -ne 0]; then
          echo "error -> $ERROR"
          return 1
        else:
         ....
         return 0
}
```

I'm trying to catch the `error` and pass it to a variable, but the variable is empty.

Comment: A fair warning: psql doesn't return error codes as you would expect. Even though there is an error, psql doesn't necessarily return an error code (returns 0). Please check the manual.

Comment: I recommend against using all-caps variable names (like `ERROR`) in the shell. There are a bunch of environment variables with special meanings, and if you ever accidentally use one of those names, it can cause weird effects. Lower- and mixed-case variables are safer in this respect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2>ERROR` sends the `stderr` output to a file named `ERROR`, not to a variable. Try the follow instead:

```
ERROR=$(sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE $1 WITH OWNER $2;" 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
```

Comment: can't do that because I want stdout to go to null, and show on the else a different message

Comment: @user3541631. I've updated my answer so that stdout is sent to `/dev/null`.